# Sequelize timestamp names

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a small issue with sequelize that I can't get around and it irritates the hell out of me.

I'm using camelCase for all my model attributes but I'm using snake case to persist them into the database (postgres). That part works fine except if I want to use sequelize [timestamps](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration) option.

If I set `underscored: false`, timestamps get persisted to the database in camelCase.

If I set `underscored: true`, they get persisted in snake_case but then they are in snake_case on the model.

**What I want to achieve is snake_case in the database and camelCase on the model for model timestamps.**

It feels like those 2 options are mutually exclusive.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can. Key is to combine model setting and field mappings. That's what I do:
When you defining your model, add following field mappings:

```
createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, field: 'created_at' },
updatedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, field: 'updated_at' },
deletedAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, field: 'deleted_at' }
```

Then in model options:

```
timestamps: true,
underscored: true
```

Works like a charm for me. In this way you can also use `paranoid` option correctly.

Comment: This is closest you can get with current version of sequlize, but it's also a hacky way to achieve what you want. I went with this solution, but I'm still not 100% happy. Reason is when I'm serializing the result I get fields `createdAt` and `created_at`. So I've created a custom toJSON method that will remove the duplicate `_at` timestamps. All in all, the best solution currently possible.

Thank you both and @gokcand and @Sergey Yarotskiy for your discussion, but I will except this answer because it did come first.

Answer (score 4):

You can do some workaround like this:

**UPDATE:** As Sergey stated in his answer, we need to keep `timestamp` option to be `true`, so I fixed that.

```
new Sequelize(foo, bar, baz, {
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
    createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        name: 'createdAt',
        field: 'created_at'
    }
    updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        name: 'updatedAt',
        field: 'updated_at'
    }
  }
});
```

[**Related issue**](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2209)

Comment: Sorry, incorrect, I achieved what topic starter asking for in my projects. According to your config, updatedAt will not be updated automatically on update, since it is not managed by Sequelize.

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy There is no automated way of doing this. Check the related issue. So I showed a workaround.

Comment: As I said, it works fine for me in production currently.

Comment: @SergeyYarotskiy Yeah okay but yours is also workaround? There is a need to modify the field mappings in both cases.

Comment: Yes, agree, but in my case, result will be exactly as desired. Sequelize will manage these fields correctly. That's what the question was. And in your case updatedAt will not be updated. Don't see the reason for downvote, since my answer is totally correct. If not, please leave a constructive comment.

Comment: My answer was "No you cannot do this for timestamps", (automatically). So it is true. I showed a workaround and related Github issue. Also updated the answer. Sorry for inconvenience @SergeyYarotskiy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163000/discussion-between-sergey-yarotskiy-and-gokcand).

Comment: This works for me as well. Note the example shows this on the `new Sequelize` call. However, this (the `define` portion) is usually defined in your `config.js` file along with your connection options and then called inside `new Sequelize`

Answer (score 1):

On the server, when we start a new connection with sequelize, by default we can define which field is createdAt, updatedAt and deletedAt, like this:

```
new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
   ......,
   define: {
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at',
      deletedAt: 'deleted_at'
   },
   ......
})
```

In the case above, it will automatically work for all tables.

I have a .js file that initializes all models and associations and do the authentication with the database.

**Hope I helped in some way**

Answer (score 0):

By default Sequelize uses camelCase - both on database level, and and on a JavaScript one. If you set snake_case to true in the model ..,{ underscored: true }, then your migrations will insert snake_cased default values: 'created_at' & 'undated_at' to DB. Yet, your original model attributes still remain camel cased. If you want them to be snake cased as well, you need to define them manually like this:

```
sequelize.define('model', {
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at'
})
```