# Two columns additonal copy of created_at and updated_at being returned with different alias

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Booking model which contains created_at and updated_at attributes. I am using association and making use of joins. But when i am doing this i am get createdAt, created_at for attribute created_at and updatedAt, updated_at for attribute updated_at. I am unable to figure what i making it to return 2 column for single attribute.

models/booking.js

```
...

Booking.init({
    booking_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    slot_time: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true
    },
    is_active: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        required: true,
        is:/^[01]$/,
        defaultValue: 1
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW

    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    }
},{
    sequelize,
    modelName:'booking',
    underscored: true
});

...
```

models/index.js

```
...
   var result = await Store.findAll({
            where: { owner_id: data['owner_id']},
            include: [{
                model: booking,
                where: {
                    slot_time: {
                        [Op.gte]: start_date
                    },
                    is_active: 1
                }
            }]
        });
...
```

Output:

```
            "owner_id": 1,
            "bookings": [
                {
                    "booking_id": 1,
                    "slot_time": "2020-05-19T06:30:00.000Z",
                    "is_active": 1,
                    "created_at": "2020-05-18T08:39:38.000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-05-18T08:39:38.000Z",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-18T08:39:38.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-05-18T08:39:38.000Z",
                    "customer_id": 1,
                    "store_id": 2
                },
                {
                    "booking_id": 5,
                    "slot_time": "2020-05-19T11:30:00.000Z",
                    "is_active": 1,
                    "created_at": "2020-05-18T08:49:13.000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-05-18T08:49:13.000Z",
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-18T08:49:13.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-05-18T08:49:13.000Z",
                    "customer_id": 1,
                    "store_id": 2
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Sequelize adds timestamps to your table's model. These `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields are the default ones.
If You want to set custom names for these fields, use [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209543/sequelize-timestamp-names).
See [API reference](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html) for additional info.